# Mysql regenerate missing IDs from 1 to N

Tags: mysql

I have a table with indexed column `id2`. After using this table inserting/deleting records, there are some missing records. `id2` starts like this

> 1,2,3,4,8,9,13,55,66,67,68 .... 928746

How can I regenerate the sequence of `id2` so it does not have missing numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6....]? Additionally, `id2` order must be consistent with `ts` field, which is unix timestamp for record insertion.

Is it possible to do with mysql query, without any code (PHP)?

P.S Nothing relies on these IDS i can change them freely , i just want to do that . any hints ?

Comment: This depends. If there are tables which have foreign keys refering to that id, you have to change them too. Could get tricky. What's the purpose of regenerating the id's in order?

Comment: I agree, sounds pointless and could cause lots of problems if anything relies on those IDs. Maybe a better idea would be to use the missing keys and be able to re-use them again for any new records?

Comment: nothing relies on these IDs , they are used for limiting the output of records instead of using the `limit` , as `limit` is useless on tables with +5000000 records !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @rownum=0;
UPDATE [table] t, (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, [table].* FROM [table]) r
SET t.[field] = r.rownum
WHERE (t.[primary_key] = r.[primary_key])
```

Replace [table] by your table name, [field] by your field name, and [primary_key] by the primary key column name

from : http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,402,108189